# Debian: How to use autoconf for hppa64

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, autoconf

I am trying to cross-build the following autoconf-based project to hppa64 (currently using Debian/sid system).

Steps so far:

```
% sudo apt-get install gcc-hppa64-linux-gnu
% wget http://www.chronox.de/libkcapi/libkcapi-1.3.1.tar.xz
% tar xf libkcapi-1.3.1.tar.xz
% cd libkcapi-1.3.1
% autoreconf -i
% ./configure --host=hppa64-linux-gnu  --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-kcapi-rngapp
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for hppa64-linux-gnu-strip... hppa64-linux-gnu-strip
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... hppa64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for hppa64-linux-gnu-gcc... hppa64-linux-gnu-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/libkcapi-1.3.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

With:

```
% hppa-linux-gnu-gcc --version
hppa-linux-gnu-gcc (Debian 11.2.0-9) 11.2.0
```

and

```
% x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc --version
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Debian 11.2.0-16) 11.2.0
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: What I am missing is any information about the content of `config.log` ("`See \`config.log' for more details`").

Answer (score 1):

Solution is:

```
% sudo apt-get install g++-hppa-linux-gnu
```

not clear what I was missing in the first place since project is C only.